# how to use posix named semaphore in c with shared memory between two processes on linux?

Tags: c, posix, ipc, shared-memory, semaphore

I am trying to synchronize two proccesses to read and write into shared memory.  Here is `a_process.c`:

```
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <sys/mman.h>
 #include <semaphore.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 #define SHM_PATH        "/instant_messaging"
 #define SHM_SIZE         50
 #define SEM_PATH        "/sem_instant_messaging"

 char *sendbuff;

 int main()
 {
     //sahred memory setting 
     //shm_unlink(SHM_PATH);
     int shmfd;

     shmfd = shm_open(SHM_PATH, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
     if (shmfd < 0) {
         perror("In shm_open()");
         exit(1);
     }

     int shm_size = SHM_SIZE;

     ftruncate(shmfd, shm_size); 
     sendbuff = (char*) mmap(NULL, shm_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
             MAP_SHARED, shmfd, 0);
     if (sendbuff == NULL) {
        perror("In mmap()");
        exit(1);
     }

     //semaphore setting 
     sem_unlink(SEM_PATH);

     sem_t * sem1;

     sem1 = sem_open(SEM_PATH, O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
     printf("before while\n");
     //setmemshr();
     //setsem();
     while (1) {
         int status = sem_wait(sem1);

         if (status != 0)
         {
             perror("in sem_wait");
         }
         printf("after wait\n");
         printf("%s\n",sendbuff);
         scanf("%s",sendbuff);
         sem_post(sem1);
         //sleep(3);
     }
 }
```

and here is `b_process.c`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHM_PATH        "/instant_messaging"
#define SHM_SIZE         50
#define SEM_PATH        "/sem_instant_messaging"  //dddddddddd

char *sendbuff;

int main()
{
    //sahred memory setting
    //shm_unlink(SHM_PATH); 
    int shmfd;

    shmfd = shm_open(SHM_PATH, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
    if (shmfd < 0) {
        perror("In shm_open()");
        exit(1);
    }

    int shm_size = SHM_SIZE;

    ftruncate(shmfd,shm_size);
    sendbuff = (char*) mmap(NULL, shm_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
            MAP_SHARED, shmfd, 0);
    if (sendbuff == NULL) {
        perror("In mmap()");
        exit(1);
    }

    //semaphore setting 
    sem_unlink(SEM_PATH);

    sem_t *sem1;

    sem1 = sem_open(SEM_PATH, O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);   

    while (1) {
        printf("before wait %d\n", *sem1);
        int status = sem_wait(sem1);

        if (status != 0)
        {
            perror("in sem_wait");
        }
        printf("after wait %d\n", *sem1);
        printf("%s", sendbuff);
        scanf("%s", sendbuff);
        sem_post(sem1);
    }
}
```

I have spent a lot of time debugging this and reading man pages, but it seems that although shared memory works and semaphore post and wait work within each process's address space, the two processes do not either one affect the data the other sees in the shared memory region.

Does anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: It looks ok for me, why do you say it doesn't affect the value in the other process?

Comment: Yeah... stuff like this is best tested and debugged on the system/environment it is failing on.  OP, that would be yours.

Comment: @Mr.E when i hit sem_wait(sem1); it should block the other process but it doesn't although the value at *sem1 get decremented from 1 to 0

Comment: cant you find any unusual thing at the code @MartinJames

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to unlink the semaphore from both programs, because sem_unlink will remove the semaphore name immediately, but the semaphore itself remains alive until the last user closes it. That makes me think that you're actually working on two different semaphores... Can you test with just an unlink in the program you start first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things in your code that are suspicious, but one combination of things stands out as definitely wrong: both processes perform a `sem_unlink()` followed immediately by a `sem_open()` on the semaphore path.  This can have the effect of the two procs using the same semaphore only if you are absurdly lucky, such that both `sem_unlink()`s are performed before either `sem_open()` is performed.  Otherwise, whichever process goes second will unlink the semaphore created by the first, and instead create and use its own.  Both processes will proceed, each using its own, independent semaphore.

I also find it a bit suspicious that both processes `ftruncate()` the shared memory region, and especially that they do so before synchronizing (or would do if the procs were effectively synchronizing at all).  I think you should make one process responsible for setting up the shared memory segment; the other needs only open and map it.  Correct your semaphore initialization, and use the semaphore to ensure that the shared memory is sized before either program proceeds to using it.

Comment: yes you are right i removed 'sem_unlink' and i used 'fstat' to pass the size of the shared memory to the other process(instead of ftruncate()) and it is working now but it has some random  behavier sometimes i don't know why

Comment: It's difficult to guess what "random behavior" might be, but perhaps it is related to this erroneous code in `b_process.c`: `printf("before wait %d\n", *sem1)`.  There is no reason to think that a `sem_t` object can successfully be interpreted as an `int`, which that code (and similar code later) assumes.  If you want to print the semaphore's value, then you can retrieve it via `sem_getvalue()`.

Comment: i used `sem_getvalue` although it doesn't seem to be the problem, the problem goes away when i simply put a `sleep(1)` statement after `sem_post()` it seem it gives the the other process time to react to the semaphore before the first processs loops again and and `sem_wait()` for the second time. is this correct mr john?

Comment: @mohammed, you still haven't explained what the remaining problem *is*.  If it is that you expect the programs to alternate but they do not, then putting a `sleep(1)` after each `sem_post()` is a crude hack that will likely make the programs *usually* cooperate as expected.  A more reliable solution to such a problem would involve using two semaphores instead of one.  Each program would wait on its own semaphore and post the other program's semaphore.

Comment: yes @john the problem is that i expect them to alternate but they don't do that **all the time** and i am not planing of course on using `sleep()` and i will try what you said but why, is it nature that semaphore behave that way i don't see any reason this stupid chunk of code doesn't work properly is it has something to do with scheduling in the kenel

Comment: @mohammed, yes, it is basically a scheduling issue.  There is no guarantee that threads will return from waiting on a given semaphore in the same order that they started waiting on it.  It is possible and even likely that a thread that posts a semaphore and then immediately waits on that same semaphore will proceed without blocking, regardless of any other threads that may already have been waiting on that semaphore.

Comment: yeah you are right john, i did it, i used two semaphore and it is working just great thank you john for helping out i appreciate that.